# how to have a constant variable work dynamically in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-conversion, jqwidget

Can anyone help me with the javascript here?
I need to know how to make the "Year" in this code dynamic.

```
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, { 
    async: false, 
    autoBind: true,

    beforeLoadComplete: function (records) {
        newRecords = new Array(
            { Year: 2012, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }, 
            { Year: 2013, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }, 
            { Year: 2014, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }
        );

        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var currentRecord = records[i];

            switch (currentRecord.Year) {
                case "2012":
                    newRecords[0]["Site" + currentRecord.SiteId] =       
                        parseFloat(currentRecord.Count);
                    break;

                case "2013":
                    newRecords[1]["Site" + currentRecord.SiteId] = 
                        parseFloat(currentRecord.Count);
                    break;

                case "2014":
                    newRecords[2]["Site" + currentRecord.SiteId] = 
                        parseFloat(currentRecord.Count);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return newRecords;
    },

    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error loading "' + source.url + '" : ' + error);
    }
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated! 
Bacially I have json data coming in this format:

```
{"Year":"2012","SiteId":"In Process","Count":6},{"Year":"2012","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":3},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"In process","Count":4},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":3},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"Under Observati","Count":1},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"In Process","Count":7},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":39},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"Under Observati","Count":1}
```

Since I am querying database for this data I am not sure how many records I will get. But I know for each year there are at max 4 SiteId's (In Process, Resolved, Under Observati, Temp. Repair). I need to bind the data based on each year. Like

```
{Year:2012,In Process:6,Resolved:3}, 
{year:2013, In Process:4,Resolved:3, Under Observation:1}
```

Comment: do you just need `new Date().getFullYear()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: Also, `switch`ing on explicit strings like that is a very bad habit to get into ;)  Is that what you want to change?

Comment: You say dynamic, yet you have set it implicitly in your newRecords array.  Did you just do that to provide an example of the JSON data elements that your AJAX queries return. Are you trying to dynamically add year cases to your switch statement. Please provide additional details on what your desired outcome is as well as which specific date instance you are trying to make dynamic (in the switch or in the newRecords array?)

Comment: yes! I need to add to add 'Year' dynamically. As in I dont know what the length of my year array will be or how to combine it. Here is an example of how my data looks like: 

{"Year":"2012","SiteId":"In Process","Count":6},{"Year":"2012","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":3},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"In process","Count":4},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":3},{"Year":"2013","SiteId":"Under Observati","Count":1},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"In Process","Count":7},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"Resolved","Count":39},{"Year":"2014","SiteId":"Under Observati","Count":1}

Comment: @Korgrue I apologize for not providing enough information. I have updated my question. Also I am trying to implement this one graph here if this helps:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_column_series_1.htm?arctic

Comment: Please give your question a title which says what it is about.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I have updated the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use external lib, I'd suggest [Lodash](https://lodash.com/).
You could use the [indexBy](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) function to properly transform your `newRecords` array in this way:

```
_.indexBy(newRecords, 'Year');
```

If `newRecords` (from your question) is:

```
[
    { Year: 2012, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }, 
    { Year: 2013, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }, 
    { Year: 2014, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 }
]
```

`_.indexBy(newRecords, 'Year');` returns:

```
{ 
    '2012': { Year: 2012, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 },
    '2013': { Year: 2013, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 },
    '2014': { Year: 2014, Site1: 0, Site2: 0, Site3: 0, Site4: 0 } 
}
```

Then you can iterate through any of those new "year-field-based" sub-objects to count any parameter across sub-objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's great!  solved that problem through a very complex sort of way. But I can used this for another thing! that helped!

Comment: @random yoy may also consider the lodash function 'groupBy' which maybe does your job